# Differences between Honda front grille part numbers

Tags: honda, civic, parts, replace

I was looking for a replacement of my front grille (there is a huge crack on it) for my 2014 Honda Civic EX Sedan.

I think that this is a reference code for the part **HO1200216** but I found in the estore of [Honda](http://estore.honda.com/honda/parts/view-honda-parts-catalog-detail.asp?m=2014-civic-4-ex-cvt&sn=&b=B%20%2045&dl=#002) that the part number is **71121-TR3-A11** (price between $115 - $159)

But in some pages (mostly [eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/HONDA-OEM-13-14-Civic-Grille-71121TR3A01-/131482625006)) have the same part but with another number **71121-TR3-A01** (price between $50 - $89)

Does anyone know the difference? Material, composition, original, quality, etc. All pages state that is compatible with my car.

I don't understand in some pages when they say OE Replacement and others OEM (I think this is a original part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there are two different grills (at least) for different models of your vehicle.

[71121-TR3-A01](http://www.hondapartsnow.com/genuine/honda~base~fr~grille~71121-TR3-A01.html) fits the following vehicles:

[image]

[71121-TR3-A11](http://www.hondapartsnow.com/genuine/honda~base~fr~grille~71121-TR3-A11.html) fits the following vehicles:

[image]

So it's basically the difference between the GX and EX models in this instance.

Comment: As far as I know, the GX runs with natural gas but the body shape of the car between GX and EX are different?  So if I buy the grille which is supposed to be to the GX model it won't fit on my EX? Or it's just a code to differentiate them?

Comment: My "bet" is, it will fit your car without issue. There will probably be some type of visual cue which is different between the two. I doubt you'd have any issues fitting it, tough. Who knows why it is so much cheaper. I think that'd be something you'd have to ask Honda about.